# How can I scrape div with jsoup if it has class like this class="Mb(25px)"

Tags: jsoup

I want to scrape some data from a webpage. 
I tried using this code:

```
Elements temp = doc.select("div.Mb(25px)");
```

And then get all of the p tags inside div tag:

```
for(Element movies: temp){
        System.out.println( movies.getElementsByTag("p").first().text());
    }
```

But it is not working..

Can You please help me?

Comment: There might be few reasons: 1. The page uses javascript to load the content you are looking for, so you'll have to try another aproach since jsoup cannot parse it. 2. The server is sending you a different page then the one you see in your browser - you can fix it by adding the user-agent string to your request.

Comment: Change you selector to this: `Elements temp = doc.select("div[class=Mb(25px)]");`